# The value of World center mode in AR camera doesn't change

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am new in unity and vuforia library. I make a simple AR application in unity by vuforia. I set `DEVICE_TRACKING` for `World center mode` in AR camera.
Now I  change `World center mode` to `Camera` but after build project the value of `World center mode` change again to first value `DEVICE_TRACKING`, and I can't change value.

what's wrong?!

[image: this is screen shot]

Comment: How do you know that it goes back to `first device` as a center mode?